# Emulate Chrome screen size from command line

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Is it possible to emulate the screen size (for Chrome) by running chrome with some command line arguments (on Windows)?

Thanks,
Khachatur

[image]

Comment: By the way , what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the option ( i didn't test it )

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --window-size=640,480

here is the list of other command line for Chrome

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: This does not work. Our test server has small screen resolution. We want to perform automatic browser tests with bugger resolution.

Comment: i tried a test and it works ... i have updated my answer with a real example